# ASPxGridView Pager disappears

Tags: paging, pager, aspxgridview

I use the ASPxGridView with paging, pager settings is next:

```
<SettingsPager
    Mode="ShowPager"
    Position="Bottom"
    Visible="true">
```

Also I have a CustomButtonInitialize event:

```
protected void gridViewInvoices_CustomButtonInitialize(object sender, ASPxGridViewCustomButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (!e.IsEditingRow)
    {
        Invoice invoice = (Invoice)gridViewInvoices.GetRow(e.VisibleIndex);
        if (invoice != null)
        {
            if (e.ButtonID == "btnConfirmPayment")
            {
                e.Visible = invoice.PaymentConfirmedDate.HasValue ?
                    DefaultBoolean.False : DefaultBoolean.Default;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I open the page with this grid the pager disappears but if I comment my CustomButtonInitialize event:

```
protected void gridViewInvoices_CustomButtonInitialize(object sender, ASPxGridViewCustomButtonEventArgs e)
{
    /*if (!e.IsEditingRow)
    {
        Invoice invoice = (Invoice)gridViewInvoices.GetRow(e.VisibleIndex);
        if (invoice != null)
        {
            if (e.ButtonID == "btnConfirmPayment")
            {
                e.Visible = invoice.PaymentConfirmedDate.HasValue ?
                    DefaultBoolean.False : DefaultBoolean.Default;
            }
        }
    }*/
}
```

Pager appears again, how can I fix it and how is pager depend on this event (*CustomButtonInitialize*)?

Best regards, Alex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jo,

Try also checking this:

```
if (e.CellType == GridViewTableCommandCellType.Data)
```

If that doesn't help then please contact our support team and they can help you figure it out:
http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/CreateIssue.aspx?issuetype=Question